# Can I receive my Canadian tourist visa sticker at a different consulate than the one I applied at?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada, tourist-visas

I am a student living in the US and I applied for a tourist visa to Canada. My visa application was approved and the embassy has asked me to submit my passport. The stamping time is around 15 days but I am leaving to India to visit my family so I won't be able to submit my passport for stamping.

Is it possible to get my visa stamped from an embassy in India?

Comment: Why the down vote people?

Comment: I would just call the Canadian embassies in India, and see what they say. http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/india-inde/contact-contactez.aspx?lang=eng&menu_id=17

Comment: Hi What happen to this? did you happen to have Canada student visa sticker in India? If Yes, what are the procedures happened? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have your Canada visa stamped in a location different from that in which you applied. To find out whether your request would be accommodated, you would have to contact CIC through the US visa applicaton centre in which you applied, and identify the appropriate centre in India.